# R gplots heatmap.2 - key is unstable using breaks parameter (warning: unsorted 'breaks' will be sorted before use)

Tags: r, legend, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering, gplots

I'm visualizing a data set with the `heatmap.2` function from the `gplots` package in R.  Basically I'm performing a hierarchical clustering analysis on the original data, while forcing the heatmap to display a limited version of the data (between -3 and +3) to limit the effect of outliers on the appearance of the heatmap, while still retaining the original clustering.  When I use the full data set (`fullmousedatamat`), it works just fine.  However, when I use a partial data set (`partialmousedatamat`), and want to plot it using the same key as the full data set, a couple colors are dropped out of the key and I can't figure out why.

Here is a gist containing the relevant data sets and analyses:

https://gist.github.com/jeffbruce/7412f567ac57fe1721a3

Notice how the 4th color on either side of the centre white color are dropped out.  This feels like a bug to me maybe.  I get the following warning message which I'm not sure how to interpret:

```
Warning message:
In image.default(z = matrix(z, ncol = 1), col = col, breaks = tmpbreaks,  :
  unsorted 'breaks' will be sorted before use
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same issue and I had to go through the code for `heatmap.2` to figure it out.

It turns out that `symkey=T`, which is the default, adds the extreme values of the data at both ends of `breaks`, rendering it un-sorted:

```
tmpbreaks <- breaks
  if (symkey) {
    max.raw <- max(abs(c(x, breaks)), na.rm = TRUE)
    min.raw <- -max.raw
    tmpbreaks[1] <- -max(abs(x), na.rm = TRUE)
    tmpbreaks[length(tmpbreaks)] <- max(abs(x), na.rm = TRUE)
  }
```

Therefore, the simple way to solve this is adding `symkey=F` if you are providing your own breaks.